# Update Button Color in ListView based on FireBase entry

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web

I have the following problem and just cannot solve it... I am building some kind of question/answer (Yes/No) app and want to achieve that if a button was pressed (an answer was given) the button stays highlighted with a color. So if a user goes back to a previous button he can see which answer he gave. Right now it is like that, all the questions come out of firebase with the structure

```
final CollectionReference _questionsCollectionReference =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("content")
              .doc(content)
              .collection("block")
              .doc(block)
              .collection("questions");
```

If a user answers a question it will get saved in his User Profile under

```
final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    await firestoreInstance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user!.id)
        .collection("content")
        .doc(content)
        .collection("block")
        .doc(block)
        .collection("questions")
        .doc(question)
        .set({
      "answer": answer, //FieldValue.arrayUnion([someData]),
    }).then((_) {
      print("success!");
    });
```

Now it should basically be like, if the answer in the user path == "yes", colorize the "yes" button.
the question_view.dart
Here we build the view with a PageViewBuilder and give it a QuestionItem

```
import 'package:fbapp/ui/shared/ui_helpers.dart';
import 'package:fbapp/ui/widgets/question_item.dart';
import 'package:fbapp/viewmodels/questions_view_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:stacked/stacked.dart';

class QuestionsView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String block;
  final String content;
  const QuestionsView({Key? key, required this.block, required this.content})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelBuilder<QuestionsViewModel>.reactive(
        viewModelBuilder: () => QuestionsViewModel(),
        onModelReady: (model) => model.fetchPosts(content, block),
        builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              body: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    verticalSpace(35),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 80,
                          child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: model.questions != null
                            ? Center(
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 700,
                                  height: 450,
                                  child: PageView.builder(
                                    controller: model.getPageController(),
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                    itemCount: model.questions!.length,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                        QuestionItem(
                                            question: model.questions![index],
                                            content: content,
                                            block: block,
                                            nextPage: model.nextPage,
                                            saveCurrentUserAnswer:
                                                model.saveCurrentUserAnswer,
                                            getCurrentUserAnswer:
                                                model.getCurrentUserAnswer),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            : Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(
                                      Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                                ),
                              ))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ));
  }
}
```

question_item.dart

```
import 'package:fbapp/app/app.locator.dart';
import 'package:fbapp/models/question.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stacked_services/stacked_services.dart';

class QuestionItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Question? question;
  final String? content;
  final String? block;
  final String? id;
  final void Function()? nextPage;
  final Future Function(
          String content, String block, String? the question, String answer)?
      saveCurrentUserAnswer;
  final Future Function(String content, String block, String? question)?
      getCurrentUserAnswer;
  const QuestionItem(
      {Key? key,
      this.question,
      this.nextPage,
      this.saveCurrentUserAnswer,
      this.content,
      this.block,
      this.id,
      this.getCurrentUserAnswer})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flex(
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Card(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.security),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.info),
                      onPressed: () {
                        final DialogService _dialogService =
                            locator<DialogService>();
                        _dialogService.showDialog(
                            dialogPlatform: DialogPlatform.Material,
                            title: "Info",
                            description: question!.info);
                      },
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text("some nice text"),
                    title: Text(question!.q!),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 50),
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                        size: Size(50, 50), // button width and height
                        child: ClipOval(
                          child: Material(
                            color: "yes" ==
                                    getCurrentUserAnswer!(
                                            content!, block!, question!.id)
                                        .toString()
                                ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 144, 132, 1)
                                : Colors.grey, // button color
                            child: InkWell(
                              splashColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 144, 132, 1),
                              // splash color
                              onTap: () {
                                nextPage!();
                                saveCurrentUserAnswer!(
                                    content!, block!, question!.id, "yes");
                              },
                              // button pressed
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.thumb_up,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ), // icon
                                  Text(
                                    "Yes",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ), // text
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 100, height: 100),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                        size: Size(50, 50), // button width and height
                        child: ClipOval(
                          child: Material(
                            color: "no" ==
                                    getCurrentUserAnswer!(
                                            content!, block!, question!.id)
                                        .toString()
                                ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 144, 132, 1)
                                : Colors.grey, // button colorr
                            child: InkWell(
                              splashColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 144, 132, 1),
                              // splash color
                              onTap: () {
                                nextPage!();
                                saveCurrentUserAnswer!(
                                    content!, block!, question!.id, "no");
                              },
                              // button pressed
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.thumb_down,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ), // icon
                                  Text(
                                    "No",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ), // text
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

That's how I build my page with the "yes" and "no" buttons.
This is the question_view_model.dart where we reference the firebase functions to save and get answers like so:

```
...
Future saveCurrentUserAnswer(
      String content, String block, String? question, String answer) async {
    await _fireStoreService!.saveCurrentUserAnswer(
        _authenticationService!.currentUser, content, block, question, answer);
  }

  Future getCurrentUserAnswer(
      String content, String block, String? question) async {
    await _fireStoreService!.getCurrentUserAnswer(
        _authenticationService!.currentUser, content, block, question);
  }
...
```

and the firebase functions to do it:

```
...
Future saveCurrentUserAnswer(User? user, String content, String block,
      String? question, String answer) async {
    final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    await firestoreInstance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user!.id)
        .collection("content")
        .doc(content)
        .collection("block")
        .doc(block)
        .collection("questions")
        .doc(question)
        .set({
      "answer": answer, //FieldValue.arrayUnion([someData]),
    }).then((_) {
      print("success!");
    });
  }

  Future<String> getCurrentUserAnswer(
      User? user, String content, String block, String? question) async {
    String answer = "";
    try {
      final DocumentReference _answerCollectionReference = FirebaseFirestore
          .instance
          .collection("users")
          .doc(user!.id)
          .collection("content")
          .doc(content)
          .collection("block")
          .doc(block)
          .collection("questions")
          .doc(question);
      var answerDocumentSnapshot = await _answerCollectionReference;
      await answerDocumentSnapshot.get().then((a) {
        if (a.exists) {
          answer = a["answer"];
        } else {
          answer = "";
        }
      });
      print("Answer: $answer");
      return answer;
    } catch (e) {
      return e.toString();
    }
  }
...
```

The `getCurrentUserAnswer` prints successfully the answer (always 2 times, not sure why...)

```
Cont: 00_DSGVO -- Block: b1
2
Answer: no
2
Answer: yes
success!
```

But the button never changes the color. I also tried it with Stateful and setState and Stateless and ValueNotifier, but somehow it doesn't work. One problem is that it have to check first if there is an answer, than rebuild the UI (or only the button) but it is building it first and afterwards checking for the answer...

Comment: I don't think it's helpful to share the entire files, just the relevant bits. See [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I didn't read through the entire code but that seems like a typical example of basic state management. You can use [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), for example. You can just create a provider  above a shared ancestor, and all the widgets below that will have access to that same instance. If you make a change to that instance, that change is available to all the child widgets, even if you change pages.

Comment: you are right @lenz, but sometimes its hard to find a middle way to understand what someone wants to achieve and the minimal example :) thats why I posted a little bit more around to understand the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out with some help, the answer was to use a FuturBuilder to wrap the question_item and set the future to getCurrentUserAnswer.

```
   return FutureBuilder(
      future: getCurrentUserAnswer!(content!, block!, question!.id),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) { return Flex(...
```